# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android

There are a lot of articles pointing to the same error but none appeared to fix my problem. So I am posting it

I have a fragment layout below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyAppointmentFragment" >

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/fragment_text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the activity layout below

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context=".IndexActivity" 
   >
    <fragment 
    android:name="com.example.helloworld.MyAppointmentFragment" 
    android:id="@+id/myappointment_fragment"              
    android:layout_weight="1"              
    android:layout_width="0dp"              
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the java source for the activity that is throwing this error

```
package com.example.helloworld;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class IndexActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
      }
}

package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
* A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass. Activities that
* contain this fragment must implement the
* {@link MyAppointmentFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface to
* handle interaction events. Use the {@link MyAppointmentFragment#newInstance}
* factory method to create an instance of this fragment.
* 
*/
public class MyAppointmentFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment using
 * the provided parameters.
 * 
 * @param param1
 *            Parameter 1.
 * @param param2
 *            Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment MyAppointmentFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static MyAppointmentFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MyAppointmentFragment fragment = new MyAppointmentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public MyAppointmentFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_appointment, container,
            false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement   
          OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated to
 * the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

  }
```

When launched in an emulator I get the following error

```
02-20 13:21:42.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 13:21:42.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1290): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.IndexActivity}:  
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
02-20 13:21:42.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1290):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
```

The Android version I am using is 4.3 and  minSdkVersion="13" and targetSdkVersion="18"

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue

Complete Stack Trace Below

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.IndexActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    at com.example.helloworld.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.helloworld.IndexActivity@4174c9f8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
    at com.example.helloworld.MyAppointmentFragment.onAttach(MyAppointmentFragment.java:85)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:883)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Modified the original post to include the complete stack trace. I noticed from the stacktrace that it is complaining on

Comment: must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener at com.example.helloworld.MyAppointmentFragment.onAttach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.helloworld.IndexActivity@4174c9f8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Your `IndexActivity` class is supposed to implement some `OnFragmentInteractionListener` interface, and it does not.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite late cause I also faced the same problem and no solution was working for me. If none of the other areas like `onFragmentInteractionListener()` have problem then check for

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

as this method is deprecated replace it with

```
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a string named fragment_text

```
android:text="@string/fragment_text"
```

in your strings.xml file in the values folder. Even if you have, try doing a project 'clean' as well.